# scala read the resource File from other Module

Tags: scala

I am trying to read the configuration file from the resouces. Is there any good methods to read the file from the resouces folder directly from the different Module in scala. I find lot of methods in Java.

Is there any scala specific methods.

Project Structure

```
Module1
- main
-- java
-- resources 
-- scalaresources
--- commandFiles 

Module2
- main
-- java
-- resources 
-- scalaresources
--- commandFiles
```

Comment: What kind of configuration? How do you use it (mean, as properties? as typesafe config? anyhow else?)? Is it supposed to use your application outside IDE which you use to develop?

Comment: @Evgeny I want to get the path and pass the path as parameter to read the file

Comment: I understand meaning of `...directly from the different Module..` I mean file type, configuration you use and so on, but does not matter, it is not that important, added answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add third module with config only (if nothing else should be shared between modules). And add this module as dependency for two others. If your modules are used independently outside your dev environment, direct path access will stop working as soon as you build your code and try to run.

Even if your application should work only in your dev environment, you need to follow right practice and add third module.